# android custom theme xml documentation?

Tags: java, android, android-theme

where can I find some official documentation for android theme xml definitions like android:windowBackground, android:colorForeground, android:colorForegroundInverse, android:colorBackground etc, having a difficult time locating this in the android developer site, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reference of available style attributes that you can use to define a style or theme (e.g., "windowBackground" or "textAppearance"), see [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) or the respective View class for which you are creating a style.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html